# symfony3 image is not uploaded

Tags: image-uploading, symfony

In AppBundle\Etity\Image I have:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="images")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $path;
    /**
     * @Assert\Image(maxSize="10M", mimeTypes="image/jpeg", minWidth = 600, minHeight = 400)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $file;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $alt;

    private $temp;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $alt
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    public function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'images/full';
    }

    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;


    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();

        if ($file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is used in AppBundle\Entity\Post.php like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade="all")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $teaserImage;
```

In AppBundle\Form\Type\PostType.php I have this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Entity\Post;

/**
 * Defines the form used to create and manipulate blog posts.
 */
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', null, array('label' => 'Title'))
            ->add('summary', null, array('label' => 'Summary'))
            ->add('teaserImage', 'AppBundle\Form\Type\ImageType', array('label' => 'Image'))
            ->add('content', null, array(
                'attr' => array('rows' => 20),
                'label' => 'Content',
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post',
        ));
    }
}
```

For some reason the images are not uploaded to the specified directory (or anywhere else) and I am not sure what I did wrong. I would be grateful for any insights.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to

```
return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
```

In this case I changed the previous line to:

```
return __DIR__ . '/../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
```

That is because my entity is located in src/AppBundle/Entity and to go to root directory it needs to hop 3 directories back.
Also it is a bad idea to hard-code paths in entities. I modified my example accordingly.

Comment: Another thing is you should always check if the directory you want to write to exists.